# Using induction, verify that the equation is true for every positive integer $n$.

Tags: proof-explanation

> Using induction, verify that the following equation is true for every positive integer $n$. $$r^0 + r^1 +\ldots+ r^n < \frac{1}{1−r},$$ for all $n ≥0$, and $0 < r < 1$.

I am completely stuck on how to approach this problem after the base case has been proven. Can anyone help me out?

*Edit.* I apologize for not explaining more. I did not understand that we could still use $r$ as a constant in this case to solve for $n$. I was of the understanding that I would also have to prove $r$ using induction and did not understand how that would be possible while proving $n$.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Use the formula for the sum of a finite geometric sequence on the left-hand side.

Comment: Use the finite sum of geometric sequence. When you do that, try dividing it into two parts and notice something about it.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: @Gary I apologize for not adding more. My confusion stemmed from the fact that I did not realize we could treat r as a constant and just solve for n. I was trying to figure out how to solve for both r and k simultaneously. My future posts will include more detail.

Comment: @C-RAM  I apologize for not adding more. My confusion stemmed from the fact that I did not realize we could treat r as a constant and just solve for n. I was trying to figure out how to solve for both r and k simultaneously. My future posts will include more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Note that
$$
r^0 + r^1 + \ldots + r^{k} + r^{k+1} = 1 + r\cdot(r^0 + r^1 + \ldots + r^{k}).
$$
So if the inequality is true for $n=k$, then
$$
r^0 + r^1 + \ldots + r^{k} + r^{k+1} < 1 + \frac{r}{1-r}=\frac{1}{1-r};
$$
that is, it's also true for $n=k+1$.

Comment: I do not think the OP put enough effort into this to deserve a complete answer.